# How to use useMemo hook inside a response of service call in React Js

Tags: reactjs

I am declaring useMemo onload of page for pagination. It is working fine. But when I tried to declare inside a response of service call I am getting this error "React Hook "useMemo" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function". Please find the code below just for reference.

### Test.js

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect,useMemo,useRef } from 'react';

const Test = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const currentTableData = useMemo(() => {    // working fine
        const firstPageIndex = (currentPage - 1) * PageSize;
        const lastPageIndex = firstPageIndex + PageSize;
        const getData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tableData"));
        //console.log(getData)
        return getData.slice(firstPageIndex, lastPageIndex);
      }, [currentPage]);

      const formikfilter = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            month: '',
            year: '',
            amount: ''
        },
        //  validate: validatefData,
        onSubmit: values => {
            //  resetForm();
            var config = { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
            fetchData(values.year, config, (res) => {
                setPosts(res.data.items);
                const currentTableData = useMemo(() => { // getting errror
                    const firstPageIndex = (currentPage - 1) * PageSize;
                    const lastPageIndex = firstPageIndex + PageSize;
                    const getData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tableData"));
                    //console.log(getData)
                    return getData.slice(firstPageIndex, lastPageIndex);
                  }, [currentPage]);
                
            }, (err) => {
                //error
            
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error message is clear - you are calling the `useMemo` hook inside a function, not inside a *React component* or a *custom hook*. If you really want to use this hook, you would have to move it out, to the component body, but it would require significant code structure changes to be able to access the `values` property, e.g. using the `formik context`.

Anyways, the usage of `useMemo` here does not make much sense, because it is meant to avoid unnecessary, heavy *recalculations* between `re-renders`, but in your particular case, the *recalculations* will be done **only** on the `onSubmit` event, **not** between the `re-renders`. Any visible performance downsides will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

React hooks cannot have local scope in a component, they need to included in global scope. You are declaring it a function hence it won't be available outside the function and ultimately killing the purpose of using it.

What you can do is declare the memo on global scope and store the data in a state, use currentPage state in your memo dependency then change the state in callback function as you did in your component.

Also, I can't seem to understand why would you want to call memo in your callback function, if its cause you want to trigger it when you can a response then you may wanna add **posts** in your dependency array of memo.